# How can i setup Airflow with Docker on a docker network

Tags: docker-compose, airflow, nginx-reverse-proxy, airflow-webserver

I am trying to setup Airflow with docker-compose.yaml.
The Problem i am encountering is that my airflow webserver is not able to start because of this error Message:
airflow-webserver | ERROR: You need to initialize the database. Please run `airflow db init`. Make sure the command is run using Airflow version 2.8.1.

my docker compose file (edited from original: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.8.1/docker-compose.yaml):

```
version: '3.9'

---
x-airflow-common:
  &airflow-common
  # In order to add custom dependencies or upgrade provider packages you can use your extended image.
  # Comment the image line, place your Dockerfile in the directory where you placed the docker-compose.yaml
  # and uncomment the "build" line below, Then run `docker-compose build` to build the images.
  image: ${AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME:-apache/airflow:2.8.1}
  # build: .
  environment:
    &airflow-common-env
    AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: CeleryExecutor
    AIRFLOW__DATABASE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres_airflow/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND: db+postgresql://airflow:airflow@postgres_airflow/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__BROKER_URL: redis://:@redis:6379/0
    AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY: ''
    AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: 'true'
    AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: 'false'
    AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKENDS: 'airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth,airflow.api.auth.backend.session'
    # yamllint disable rule:line-length
    # Use simple http server on scheduler for health checks
    # See https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/administration-and-deployment/logging-monitoring/check-health.html#scheduler-health-check-server
    # yamllint enable rule:line-length
    AIRFLOW__SCHEDULER__ENABLE_HEALTH_CHECK: 'true'
    # WARNING: Use _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS option ONLY for a quick checks
    # for other purpose (development, test and especially production usage) build/extend Airflow image.
    _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ${_PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS:-}
  volumes:
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-./data}/dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-./data}/logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-./data}/config:/opt/airflow/config
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-./data}/plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
  user: "${AIRFLOW_UID:-50000}:0"
  depends_on:
    &airflow-common-depends-on
    redis:
      condition: service_healthy
    postgres:
      condition: service_healthy
  networks:
    - "proxy-network"

services:
  postgres_airflow:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: airflow
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: airflow
      POSTGRES_DB: airflow
    volumes:
      - ./data/postgres-db-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "airflow"]
      interval:  10s
      retries:  5
      start_period:  5s
    restart: always
    networks:
      - "proxy-network"

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
#    ports:
#      - "6379:6379"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 50
      start_period: 30s
    restart: always
    networks:
      - "proxy-network"

  airflow-webserver:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: webserver
#    ports:
#      - "8080:8080"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:8080/health"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s
    restart: always
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: my.domain.de
      LETSENCRYPT_HOST: my.domain.de
      VIRTUAL_PORT: 5556
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully
    networks:
      - "proxy-network"

  airflow-scheduler:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: scheduler
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:8974/health"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully
    networks:
      - "proxy-network"

  airflow-worker:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: celery worker
    healthcheck:
      # yamllint disable rule:line-length
      test:
        - "CMD-SHELL"
        - 'celery --app airflow.providers.celery.executors.celery_executor.app inspect ping -d "celery@$${HOSTNAME}" || celery --app airflow.executors.celery_executor.app inspect ping -d "celery@$${HOSTNAME}"'
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      # Required to handle warm shutdown of the celery workers properly
      # See https://airflow.apache.org/docs/docker-stack/entrypoint.html#signal-propagation
      DUMB_INIT_SETSID: "0"
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully
    networks:
      - "proxy-network"

  airflow-triggerer:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: triggerer
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", 'airflow jobs check --job-type TriggererJob --hostname "$${HOSTNAME}"']
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully
    networks:
      - "proxy-network"

  airflow-init:
    <<: *airflow-common
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
    # yamllint disable rule:line-length
    command:
      - -c
      - |
        if [[ -z "${AIRFLOW_UID}" ]]; then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: AIRFLOW_UID not set!\e[0m"
          echo "If you are on Linux, you SHOULD follow the instructions below to set "
          echo "AIRFLOW_UID environment variable, otherwise files will be owned by root."
          echo "For other operating systems you can get rid of the warning with manually created .env file:"
          echo "    See: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/docker-compose/index.html#setting-the-right-airflow-user"
          echo
        fi
        one_meg=1048576
        mem_available=$$(($$(getconf _PHYS_PAGES) * $$(getconf PAGE_SIZE) / one_meg))
        cpus_available=$$(grep -cE 'cpu[0-9]+' /proc/stat)
        disk_available=$$(df / | tail -1 | awk '{print $$4}')
        warning_resources="false"
        if (( mem_available < 4000 )) ; then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: Not enough memory available for Docker.\e[0m"
          echo "At least 4GB of memory required. You have $$(numfmt --to iec $$((mem_available * one_meg)))"
          echo
          warning_resources="true"
        fi
        if (( cpus_available < 2 )); then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: Not enough CPUS available for Docker.\e[0m"
          echo "At least 2 CPUs recommended. You have $${cpus_available}"
          echo
          warning_resources="true"
        fi
        if (( disk_available < one_meg * 10 )); then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: Not enough Disk space available for Docker.\e[0m"
          echo "At least 10 GBs recommended. You have $$(numfmt --to iec $$((disk_available * 1024 )))"
          echo
          warning_resources="true"
        fi
        if [[ $${warning_resources} == "true" ]]; then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: You have not enough resources to run Airflow (see above)!\e[0m"
          echo "Please follow the instructions to increase amount of resources available:"
          echo "   https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/docker-compose/index.html#before-you-begin"
          echo
        fi
        mkdir -p /sources/logs /sources/dags /sources/plugins
        chown -R "${AIRFLOW_UID}:0" /sources/{logs,dags,plugins}
        exec /entrypoint airflow version
    # yamllint enable rule:line-length
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      _AIRFLOW_DB_MIGRATE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_CREATE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME:-airflow}
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD:-airflow}
      _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ''
    user: "0:0"
    volumes:
      - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-./data}:/sources
    networks:
      - "proxy-network"

  airflow-cli:
    <<: *airflow-common
    profiles:
      - debug
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      CONNECTION_CHECK_MAX_COUNT: "0"
    # Workaround for entrypoint issue. See: https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/16252
    command:
      - bash
      - -c
      - airflow
    networks:
      - "proxy-network"

  # You can enable flower by adding "--profile flower" option e.g. docker-compose --profile flower up
  # or by explicitly targeted on the command line e.g. docker-compose up flower.
  # See: https://docs.docker.com/compose/profiles/
  flower:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: celery flower
    profiles:
      - flower
#    ports:
#      - "5555:5555"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:5555/"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: my.domain.de
      LETSENCRYPT_HOST: my.domain.de
      VIRTUAL_PORT: 5555
    networks:
      - "proxy-network"

volumes:
  postgres-db-volume:

networks:
  proxy-network:
    external: true
```

if i am using the un edited file from the airflow documentation it works flawlessly.
but i want to use airflow behind a nginx reverseproxy with letsencrypt. therfore i added the network configuration aswell as the envoirement variables for letsencrypt. I only want to expose the webserver the other containers should only be able to communicate via the docker network.

i tried to initialize the database manually like in the documentation.
i also tried to connect from an extra container the the postgres db container with command:`docker run --network proxy-network -it postgres:latest psql -h postgres_airflow -U airflow -d airflow`. that works and also the database seems to be correctly initialized (DB structure seems to be matching the Airflow requirements.
i tried to change to connection string to the ip of the container inside of the docker network.
important to mention might be that if the webserver is not able to make a connection to the database(tried with running the docker compose file without the postgres DB) i get the same error that the DB is not initialized correctly. So this error message could either mean it can connect the DB or the DB is missing the initialized schema.

Do you have some ideas on how to fix my Problem?